# How to use av_frame_unref in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

1. Can I create one AVFrame and use it for decoding of all frames? So I call `av_frame_alloc()` once, decode all frames, and then call `av_frame_unref()` once. Or I should call `av_frame_alloc` / `av_frame_unref` for *each* frame?
2. When exactly I should call av_frame_unref, before decoding or after decoding?

A.

```
av_frame_alloc()

av_frame_unref()
```

(decoding...)

B. Or this variant:

```
av_frame_alloc()
```

(decoding...)

```
av_frame_unref()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You could only use one `AVFrame` struct for the entire decoding/encoding process, by calling `av_frame_alloc()` once.
2. `av_frame_unref()` is only needed when you decide to enable reference counting for your encoding/decoding context, called for each frame.
3. Use `av_frame_free()` to free the frame struct and all its buffers at the end of your encoding/decoding process.

See ffmpeg's official examples for how to use them:
[demuxing_decoding](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/demuxing__decoding_8c_source.html)

Answer (score 3):

Reference counting is a generic process where a dynamically allocated source is shared (e.g. among multiple threads). To prevent freeing the source by a thread and put others `offside` position, this mechanism is used, often implemented with a simple atomic counter associated with the object.

The threads which accesses the source calls `addref`, that typically will increase the counter by 1 and when the thread is done using it calls `unref` and that decreases the counter (in case of ffmpeg these are `av_frame_ref` and `av_frame_unref` if I'm not mistaken).

This ensures that the source remains valid until the thread using it is done with it.

Eventually, when the counter reaches zero (no user left), the source is freed safely.